# Andriod 4.4.2 "optimizing app x of 50 android" after flash Gapps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, google-apps

I've flashed Gapps for kitkat in my andriod 4.4.2, and now when I turn on the phone, **The problem is that** always said **"optimizing app x of 50 android"**, the which take much time. (I also happened to this with a cell phone jellybean after flash Gapps)

I've tried advance factory reset from TWRP but this not change, also reflash other Gapps..

**Note:** I dont wanna update kitkat to Lollipop because lollipop have so many bugs in my phone (Azumi A50+)

Help me please, thank you very much

Comment: Download another Gapps and flash it.

Comment: I've tried it too @esQmo

Comment: Download the minimal gapps from micro to nano, from here: http://opengapps.org/

Comment: If you have a stock firmware, there may be compatibility issue with the existing Gapps.

Comment: I've tried flash nano instead of pico, but its send me error 70 (because system haven't enough space), then the playstore and services are bugged, but it solved my problem xD, I dont know but accidentally the error solved my problem, now I've reinstall 'google services and playstore' with TitaniumBackup. Thank you very much dude @esQmo

Comment: You're welcome. I'm now going to put it as an answer, just mark it as ACCEPTED for other to find it.

Comment: @esQmo ty dude, with pleasure friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a stock firmware, this might lead to an incompatibility with the existing Gapps.

Try downloading the minimal Gapps,  nano or pico package from [here](http://opengapps.org)

Comment: Note: I think that if this not work also could try remove all services of google with a tool as TitaniumBackup and reboot, then reinstall manually NOT WITH Gapps. Thank you very mucho. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Does that happens only on first and second boot or everytime you boot phone? If you use custom rom it's probably rom releated bug, contact developer and report bug.

Comment: I happends Always after load the logo, in my phone I cant use custom roms, all roms have many bugs as "the camera lost 9 Megapixels"

Comment: @Milor123 Then why did you use TWRP to flash gapps?

Comment: Its my recovery, Is it wrong to use it?

Comment: The thing is why flash gapps when you use stock rom that allredy have gapps

Comment: Because I was problem and the playstore stopped, then I had to install Gapps

Comment: You should try factory reset, not flash gapps over. However now try flashing stock rom via software on pc or via download mode (depends on phone)

Comment: Factory reset not work dude

Comment: TRY FLASHING STOCK ROM, do you even read what I wrote?

Comment: Yes it could be solved with the stock rom, but I need my data system and others things, I want not lose my system information